# PreferredBackBufferWidth/Height from GraphicsDeviceManager not working?

Tags: xna, c#

It works fine in other "projects" so it has something to do with project. 
The project im talking about here has tons of classes but nothing with graphicsdevicemanager other than game1.cs
game1.cs starts with

```
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
```

then in public game1()

```
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
```

nope, the game is still 800x600.
I have also tried adding graphics.ApplyChanges(); while I dont need it in game1 and would be calling twice, still didnt work.

HOWEVER, if I add

```
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

to "Initialize" (graphics' init is still from game1) it works

as you can see, I can fix it by going to Initialize and wasting some resource but I wonder why this is happening ? Im sure someone else in my code doesnt interfere.(I have no idea if something like this exist in properties etc. tho)

Comment: Why do you think doing it in `Initialize` wastes resources?

Comment: well I dont "think" it might be incorrect, I've read it in somewhere else. Basically game1 alredy calls applychanges and you call it twice. of course, its very minimal but should avoid it when possible. What I read might be non-sense as well, I can never be sure.

Comment: @Newell: You're quite right. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287316/165500) for the exact details of why you shouldn't be setting the resolution in `Initialize`.

Comment: are you initializing only witdh? I think you should initialize height too...

Comment: @AndrewRussell, What exactly is bad about setting it up twice? You state it in the answer you linked, but you don't say why, but I'm very curious, as I have the creating of the `GraphicsDeviceManager` in the constructor, but set the resolution in `Initialize` in my current project.

Comment: What, the double initialization isn't bad enough for you?

Comment: @AndrewRussell, Sounds like something that is quickly taken care of by the garbage collector?

Comment: Actually it's mostly unmanaged resources that will be taken care of immediately (still a CPU time cost). Another reason it's bad is that it messes with the size part way through initialisation - potentially causing exactly the issue Newell is describing. But worst of all it's just plain ugly. The idea that it's ok to code like that - just slapping things together because they *seem* to work, instead of actually understanding the API and doing things properly - is, quite frankly, appalling coding practice.

Comment: @AndrewRussell, So what you say is, never change the size in Initialize, only do it in the constructor or in Update?

Comment: Yes. For full details, see [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287316/165500) that I linked. Now, to be fair - the documentation is pretty lacking about how this works - and there are lots of incorrect code snippets floating around. Hopefully if I harp on about this loudly enough, maybe I can counteract this a bit :)

Comment: @AndrewRussell, Seems you should harp a little less loud about it. I just decompiled the Game class, and double checked, and setting the size in Initialize is perfectly valid, as the `GraphicsDeviceManager` is created just prior to calling `.Initialize`.

Comment: Trust me on this one, I've [implemented it](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/) before myself, and I spent a lot of time verifying the precise start-up order of the `Game` class. Like I said: Just because it *works* doesn't make it *correct*. In fact you've pretty much proved my point: `GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice` gets called inside `Game.Run` before `Game.Initialize`. So if you call `ApplyChanges` inside `Initialize` it's re-setting the graphics device for no good reason.

Comment: @AndrewRussell, Just because I've written an MMO network engine, doesn't make me an expert. If you look at the decompiled method `private void RunGame(bool useBlockingRun)`, you'll see that the state of the Game or it's devices doesn't change between `.Initialize` and `.Update`, except for a few private members related to the game loop and a single abstract method. Doing something in `.Initialize` and in `.Update` is the exact same, except `.Initiailze` is only called once, momentarily before the first `.Update`.

Comment: I agree that you obviously shouldn't create a new GraphicsDeviceManager outside the Game constructor, but resizing is perfectly fine in any of the virtual methods the Game class gives you.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting my point. It's "*fine*" in the sense that it will "*work*": It won't crash, it won't put your game into a weird state (ignoring unusual 3rd-party code interaction, as per the initial question). I am saying *only* two things: **1)** Calling `GDM.CreateDevice` (via `Game.Run`) followed immediately by `GDM.ApplyChanges` (in `Initialize`, but also in `LoadContent` or even in `Update` with no user interaction) causes the device to be set up, then immediately torn down and set up again. And **2)** This is a bad thing. You should just set it up right in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of many different ways that something could be sneaking in and changing the size of your backbuffer. Here are a few guesses:

- Something is hooking `PreparingDeviceSettings` and then overriding `GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth`/`Height` during the initial device setup. This seems likely if there is code in the project for configuring multisampling.
- A game component has an `Initialize` method that is doing the same thing as your own "hack" (please don't do this) and doing the equivalent of `ApplyChanges` (it could be calling `GraphicsDevice.Reset` directly, for example).
- The `GraphicsDeviceManager` class adds itself to `Services`. This is how `Game` is able to find it and use it to set up the graphics device in the first place. Perhaps something is using that as a way to go in and mess with it directly?

Probably the best way to determine when this is happening is to hook `GraphicsDeviceManager.PreparingDeviceSettings` or `GraphicsDevice.DeviceResetting` (or perhaps something else) with a blank event that contains a breakpoint (or `Debugger.Break()`). And then inspect the state that is being set up.

The other simple thing to do might be to just full text search your code for the number "600" or "800" and see if that helps you find the code responsible.

Another way, which is slow but will surely find the responsible code, is to step through the entire startup sequence of your game, line-by-line, in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are a couple of basic things i would try.

First:
rebuild your solution if you have already not done so.

Second (if that didnt work):
try to set the window to full screen, if this works then there is a problem somewhere down your code, look through it and see if you are altering the resolution (you may be doing this in a different object/class dont forget to check them).If you found any resolution changes below the public method then comment them out and try to run again.

If that didnt work then you will have to scontinue debugging, i would recommend quickly setting up an empty project and trying to change the screen resolution, if the same problem occurs there may be something wrong with your ide setup otherwise you know that there is something wrong with your solution and will have to comb through your code to find the culprit. If that doesnt work then copy all of your code into a new project.